Is this set a basis for a topology?
Is the set
$$
\{V_{n,\epsilon}\mid n\in\mathbb{N},\epsilon>0\},
$$
where $V_{n,\epsilon}=(-\infty,-n)\cup(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\cup(n,\infty)$, a basis for a topology on $\mathbb{R}$. I have proven that it satisfies the first property of a basis, i.e. For every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists $B\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B$, but I can't prove the second one, For all $B_1,B_2\in\mathcal{B}$ and every $x\in B_1\cap B_2$ there exists $B_3\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B_3\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$. Does any one know If actually this set is a basis or if it is not? And in a positive case,  how do I prove the second property? Thanks for your reading.
Here my attemp of the second property:
Define $\mathcal{B}:=\{V_{n,\epsilon}\mid n\in\mathbb{N},\epsilon>0\}$. Let $B_1,B_2\in\mathcal{B}$, then there exists $n_1,n_2\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2>0$ such that $B_1=V_{n_1,\epsilon_1}$ and $B_2=V_{n_2,\epsilon_2}$, thus
$$
B_1\cap B_2=
            [(-\infty,-)\cap(-\infty,-n_2)]\cup(-\epsilon_1,-n_2)\\
            \cup(-\epsilon_2,-n_1)\cup [(-\epsilon_1,\epsilon_1)\cap(-\epsilon_2,\epsilon_2)]\cup(n_1,\epsilon_2)\\
            \cup (n_2,\epsilon_1)\cup[(n_1,\infty)\cap(n_2,\infty)].
$$
Define $\epsilon:=\min\{\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\}$ and $n:=\max\{n_1,n_2\}$, then
$$
 B_1\cap B_2=
            (-\infty,-n)\cup(-\epsilon_1,-n_2)
            \cup(-\epsilon_2,-n_1)\cup (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\cup(n_1,\epsilon_2)
            \cup (n_2,\epsilon_1)\cup(n,\infty),
$$
Let $x\in B_1\cap B_2$. If $x\in (-\infty,-n)\cup (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\cup (n,\infty)$, then $V_{n,\epsilon}$ works for the desired $B_3$, but I can't find $B_3$ in the other cases.

Hint:$$V_{\epsilon,n}\cap V_{\delta,m}=V_{\min(\epsilon,\delta),\max(n,m)}$$

Did you actually tried the second property? It's pretty straightforward. Why don't you share what did you tried to see where you got stuck?

@jjagmathm I have already shared it

@ThomasAndrews, see my update, I don't have the same equality as you for the intersection, why?

@ThomasAndrews That's only the case if $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are small. Take for example, $V_{1/2,1}\cap V_{2,3}$

Now that I've posted that example, I think it shows that $\mathcal{B}$ is actually not a basis.

@jjagmath, what do you get $V_{1/2,1}\cap V_{3,2}$ is equal to?

Take $B_1=V_{1,\tfrac{1}{2}}$ and $B_2 = V_{3,2}$. Then $\tfrac{3}{2} \in B_1\cap B_2$, but let's see that there is no $V_{n,\epsilon}$ such that $\tfrac{3}{2} \in V_{n,\epsilon} \subseteq B_1\cap B_2$:
Suppose that there is one such $V_{n,\epsilon}$.
Since $\tfrac{1}{2} \not\in B_1\cap B_2$ then $\epsilon \le \tfrac{1}{2}$.
Since $3 \not\in B_1\cap B_2$ then $n\ge3$.
But then $\frac{3}{2} \not \in V_{n,\epsilon}$.

I think you should change the order of the subindices at leat in the equality for $B_1$

You're right, I mixed up the indices.

I can't see why you say $1/2\notin B_1\cap B_2$. Since I have done the computations and I have found that $B_1\cap B_2=(-\infty,-3)\cup(-2,-1)\cup(-1/2,1/2)\cup(1,2)\cup(3,\infty)$. Then, we do have that $1/2\in B_1\cap B_2$

$\tfrac{1}{2} \not\in B_1 \cap B_2$ because $\tfrac{1}{2} \not \in B_1$. Similarly, $3 \not\in B_1 \cap B_2$ because $3 \not \in B_2$

Why do you think that $\frac{1}{2} \in (-\infty,-3)\cup(-2,-1)\cup(-1/2,1/2)\cup(1,2)\cup(3,\infty)$?

my mistake. According to you, what is the value of $B_1\cap B_2$?

The same that you got. But don't understand why you need to write it explicitly, it is not necessary, as you can see in my proof.
